# GetAsyncKeyState(0x14) To check that Caps Lock is pressed

Tags: c#

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x14) == -32767)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("message");

            }
```

with this code I can check whether the caps lock key is pressed. however, this code does not work on some computers. code is working when I change to -32768. Why did I encounter such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) states that the least significant bit is used to tell you whether or not the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check non-zero for key press:

> ## Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. **However, you should not rely on this last behavior;** for more information, see the Remarks.
>   [...]
>
> ## Remarks
>
> [...] **Although the least significant bit of the return value indicates whether the key has been pressed since the last query, due to the pre-emptive multitasking nature of Windows, another application can call GetAsyncKeyState and receive the "recently pressed" bit instead of your application.** The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon. [...]
>   -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate